# "param is missing or the value is empty: user"

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I tried to create a `book` along with creating a `user`. So the form `Book`is nested in `User`.
But I can't go through because I had this error :

> > param is missing or the value is empty

I had a look at every question on slack where people get this error.

But none suits to my case.

So if you have any idea please feel free to help.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :books
  has_many :covers, through: :books
  has_many :commands
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
end
```

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one    :cover
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**registrations_controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    self.resource.books = Book.new
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(resource_name).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :books_attributes[:title, :author_first_name, :author_last_name])
  end
end
```

I checked `resource_name` which is properly equal to `:user`

**devise/registrations/new**

```
h2
  | Sign up
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  .field
    = f.label :email
    br
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true
  .field
    = f.label :password
    - if @minimum_password_length
      em
        | (
        = @minimum_password_length
        |  characters minimum)
    br
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off"
  .field
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    br
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off"
  = f.fields_for :books do |p|
    = p.text_field :title
    = p.text_field :author_first_name
    = p.text_field :author_last_name
  .actions
    = f.submit "Sign up"
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

---

**EDIT**

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
  root 'home#index'
end
```

**log**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for ::1 at 2017-03-10 08:59:00 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: user:
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:309:in `require'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `sign_up_params'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `new'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.7.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:232:in `call'
  puma (3.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.7.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

Started POST "/__better_errors/8c394ae550fda307/variables" for ::1 at 2017-03-10 08:59:00 +0100
```

Comment: Try to change `self.resource.books = Book.new` and `self.resource.books.build` and show the log(input params)  for a create aciton

Comment: I try that, but there are nothing interessant in the log : `ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: user:
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:309:in `require'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `sign_up_params'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `new'
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'.....`

Comment: Try changing `:books_attributes` to `:book_attributes` in your `params.permit`. If this does not help, please show the part from your server log where the request parameters are logged.

Comment: I edited my question with the full log, see above. `book_attributes` didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understand where this error came from.

When you call your params, you just need to call them in `create` action. Calling them in `new` action will produce the error.

My code after editing it :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    build_resource
    self.resource.books = Book.new
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  ......

 end
```